# ASP.NET и авторизация в БД подход

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

Здравствуйте!
У меня есть приложение на ASP.NET MVC, которое мне досталось в наследство. Для подключения к БД Oracle Database используется Entity framework.
И есть требование, чтобы пользователи во время работы были авторизованы в БД (для работы триггеров аудита). Для авторизации используется Forms authentication + 
свой Membership Provider.
В данный момент это сделано так. Пользователь авторизуется, ASP.NET выдаёт пользователю куки, происходит подключение под спец. логином к БД, пароль пользователя шифруется и кладётся в БД.
Далее, когда пользователь совершает какое-либо действие, сначала приложение получает из БД пароль, дешифрует его и создаёт новое подключение к БД с использованием логина и пароля пользователя. И с этим подключением выполняется запрос пользователя.
Мне кажется этот подход некрасивым. Как вообще правильно сделать в таком случае?

Comment: А почему бы не использовать сквозную аутентификацию - введенный пользователем пароль использовать в качестве пароля к БД?

Comment: Пароль и так используется. Проблема в хранении его между запросами. Предыдущий программист решил его хранить в БД. Можно хранить его в переменной сессии. Вся работа с БД идёт в сервисном слое.

Comment: В такой архитектуре его лучше в куках хранить. В зашифрованном виде. И чтобы кука http only.